# Short code: map, filter, lambda

Tags: python, lambda

I use Python 3.4 and I have this code:

```
result = []
    for i in r['resp']:
        for id in self.all_dicts:
            if i == id['id']:
                result.append(id)
```

Its very long, so I want to short:

```
result = list(map(filter(lambda x: x == i,self.all_dicts),r['resp']))
```

But I have an error:

```
TypeError: 'filter' object is not callable
```

How to fix that? Thanks

Comment: What does `r[resp]` contains? Can we convert it to a set?

Comment: result = [ id for i in r['resp'] for id in self.all_dicts if i == id['id'] ]

Answer (score 3):

I think you want:

```
result = [id for id in self.dicts if id['id'] in r['resp']]
```